# How to animate in Blender on 2s

Tags: animation, frame-rate

When doing animation in blender, how can you get the illusion that it was animated on 2s. I do my animation 24 FPS.

A perfect example would Spider-man into the spider verse. The entire movie is on 2s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can perform your animation using odd numbers only, then select all objects or armature you used and go to the menu: Object (or pose), animation, bake action. Set the frame step to 2, then select all the new action and set the interpolation to "constant".

[image]