# Non destructively animate on 2's

Tags: animation, armature, keyframes

Looking for a way to have an armature or any other arbitrary object animate on 2's (only change position/rotation every other frame). I cannot just hold every frame for 2, as I want camera and environment animations to be a regular 24 fps. These objects animating on 2's should be 12 fps.

Using [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153409/how-to-animate-in-blender-on-2s) method it can be done, but this method gets rid of half the animation data and formats it in a way that makes it hard to make tiny adjustments, especially when working with a complex armature, for example.

How can I "convert" a smooth animation to animate on 2's, yet keep all animation data intact so I can switch back to make adjustments if necessary?

Comment: I think you can only achieve this with Python scripting. Maybe a Python script could take animation of one object and copy it to another and then use the solution described in the linked question so this would be sort of non-destructive.

Comment: [This](https://blendermarket.com/products/stop-mo) might be of interest. I have no idea what it is or does, but seems related. Might be worth to check it out.